# Request without left outer join on childrens

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, criteria

I'am triing to make query from Hibernate criteria, but the generated query contains unnecessary joins.

My entity mapping is like that :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="A")
public class A {
    @Id 
    private Long id;

    private String champ1;
    private String champ2;
    private String champ3;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
public class B extends A {}

@Entity
@Table(name="C")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
public class C extends A {}
```

I want to execute query like this :

```
SELECT ID, CHAMP1, CHAMP2 FROM A WHERE CHAMP3 = ?
```

My Criteria is :

```
Criteria criteria = (Session)em.getDelegate()).createCriteria(A.class);

ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList();
projections.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
projections.add(Projections.property("champ1"), "champ1");
projections.add(Projections.property("champ2"), "champ2");

criteria.setProjection(projections);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("champ3", valeur));

(List<A>) criteria.list();
```

The generated request is :

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.CHAMP1,
    a.CHAMP2
FROM
    A a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    B b 
on a.ID=b.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    C c 
on a.ID=c.ID 
WHERE
    a.champ3 = ?
```

How can I do to have no left outer join in my resquest?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(polymorphisms = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)` to your parent class, or add `Restrictions.eq("class", A.class)` to the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i try your solution and the generated query is now :       select
  a.id,
        a.CHAMP1,
        a.CHAMP2,
    from
        A a 
    left outer join
        B b 
            on a.ID=b.ID 
    left outer join
        C c 
            on a.ID=c.ID 
 where
     case 
            when b.ID is not null then 1 
            when c.ID is not null then 2 
            when a.ID is not null then 0 
        end=?
  a.champ3 = ?

Comment: With which solution?  Did you try each independently?

Comment: This is not working for me either. I have tried with annotating Parent and Child classes and no luck.